# How do I correctly filter on numeric columns with custom format in Oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In our APEX reports, we use custom number formats to round numeric values to a given (user-defined precision). E.g. given this data:

```
create table round_test(pk number not null primary key, value number);
insert into round_test(pk, value) values (1, 0.11);
insert into round_test(pk, value) values (2, 0.19);
insert into round_test(pk, value) values (3, 0.20);
insert into round_test(pk, value) values (4, 0.21);
insert into round_test(pk, value) values (5, 0.23);
insert into round_test(pk, value) values (7, 0.28);
```

I've created an interactive report to display the `VALUE` column with format `999D9` (for illustration purposes, I've added an `ORIGINAL_VALUE` column that displays the data without a number format, i.e. with full precision - see screenshot below).

Now if I click the column header to filter by this column, I get duplicate values (e.g. 0.2 appears four times - once for 0.19, 0.20, 0.23 and 0.28):

[image: Filter drop down]

That's bad enough, but if I click one of these values, APEX filters by the *exact value* instead of the rounded one:

[image: Filter result]

How can I

- get rid of the duplicates in the drop-down
- force APEX to filter by the rounded value

**Note:** Creating a view with the rounded values and using that in the report definition is not a viable approach, since our reports include a custom export function that allows the users to export the data with full precision.

**UPDATE**
The SQL query for the report is quite simple:

```
SELECT 
  pk,
  value,
  value AS original_value
FROM round_test
```

The behaviour is the same in APEX 4.2 (which we currently use) and APEX 5.0 (which I used at http://apex.oracle.com to create the example).

Comment: Could you post the sql query on the report?

Comment: That's actually really confusing, and now I can't tell right away how this behaved in apex 4.2. You might want to bring this to attention on the oracle forums too.

Comment: @Typo I've added it to the question

Comment: @Tom It's the same in APEX 4.2 and APEX 5.0 (I've updated the question accordingly)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your custom export function?

Comment: @Tom It's an APEX plugin for doing Excel exports. But I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: I'm curious about the custom export function as well. If you format your values after the SQL runs, you're stuck with each formatted value representing one original value from one record. Changing the way the filters work will mean digging about in Oracle's javascript to customise interactive report functionality. I can't help thinking that sounds worse than further customising an existing custom function. Which round hole is closest to your square peg?

Comment: @Bacs So what do you suggest? Using a view as input for the report that performs the rounding, but also contains the exact values as hidden columns and uses that for the export? If possible, I'd like to avoid that (it would require changing several views, interactive reports and the export plugin) for something that should (in my opinion) be pretty straightforward (but apparently isn't due to some strange APEX limitation / bug).

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Does your export plugin ignore report columns that aren't displayed? If so, you could show your users how to do this with computed columns, and you wouldn't have to make any changes to views, reports or the plugin.

Comment: @Bacs Yes; the export plugin exports only the data that is currently displayed (rows and columns). Would the solution with computed columns require an additional user action for each export (if that's the case, it is unacceptable)?

Comment: Does the export functionality take into account conditionality of columns? If yes, a way would be to include a formatted number in the report's query in addition to the unformatted number. Don'd include the unformatted column in the report when normal, and do the reverse when the export is done. No views or such but you'd have to change the reports where you have this. Still though, this sounds more like a bug as noone would want this behaviour.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt Just about to post my answer when I noticed your question. A computed column would be set up (created and hidden) once for each report. It would only need to be amended if the user wanted to change the format mask, again for each report. Exporting would require no extra steps, however filtering on the hidden column would require using the `Actions` button to create a filter rather than just clicking the header, since of course there would be no header.

Answer (score 3):

**To eliminate duplicates on the List of values filter:**

First you need to create a LOV on Application -> Shared Components -> Other Components -> List of Values

With this sql query:

```
select distinct to_char(value,'999.9') d, round(value) r 
FROM round_test  order by 1 asc
```

Then on Report Atributes edit the column that contains the 'value' value, and in the List of Values Section specify on 'Column Filter Type': Use Named List of Values to Filter Exact Match and then on 'Named List of Values', select the one you created earlier.

**To filter by the rounded value:**

Create the report but instead of applying the format mask as you did (this maintains the actual value despite the format applied on the view) format the value on the query like this:

```
SELECT 
  pk,
  to_char(value,'999.9') value,
  value AS original_value_
FROM round_test
```

I think that will cover your needs.

[Here's a working example](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=75638)

Comment: Bottom line is you need a way of grouping the original values by the rounded values, and I agree that the SQL is probably the best place to do this, since the default Apex filter doesn't cater for it. The LOV here doesn't add anything useful though - the user still has to filter on the formatted column, and export the original column. The default Apex filter would do the exact same thing.

Comment: @Bacs the LOV removes the duplicate values on the default LOV filter

Comment: but there won't be any duplicates, since the formatting is done in the SQL rather than the report's column definition. The filter will show distinct values of the formatted value returned by the query.

Comment: @Bacs there are two different questions asked by the OP, 1- How to get rid off duplicates values 2- How to force apex to filter by the rounded value. So I answer both, but yes there's no need to apply both.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal behaviour would be to have a single report column for `value`. Clicking on the header would give the standard options, including a filter which would display (and allow searching on) rounded decimal numbers. Unfortunately Apex doesn't let you do that. The values that appear in the filter are determined using the distinct values selected in the initial report query; subsequent formatting in the report's column definition only affects how values are displayed, not the actual values, hence the apparent duplicates in the filter list.

I think the essence of your problem is that without doing some heavy customisation of the interactive report filter (good luck to you if you go that route), I think you'll have to accept having two columns for `value`, one containing the actual value, and one containing the rounded or otherwise formatted value, to be used for filtering.

As suggested elsewhere, you could create the new column in the SQL for each of your reports:

```
SELECT 
  pk,
  value,
  to_char(value, 'fm999D9') AS formatted_value
FROM round_test
```

Alternatively, if your users are willing and able, you could show them how to create a computed column from the `Actions` button:

[image: Actions->Format->Compute]

Whichever way the `formatted_value` column is created, it should be hidden in order to stop it messing up the export. Filtering would then have to be done from the `Actions` button:

[image: Actions->Filter]